# I can't read a .dat file using fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I know there are a ton of questions pertaining to this subject but I cannot get this to work. The program ran fine on my laptop, but when I try to compile and run it in the the schools Linux lab the program cannot open the file. I have tried defining the absolute file position but nothing has worked. The file name is correct and everything but when I try to run the program it displays "failed". I'm using gedit and compiled the program with bash.

```
    ifstream fin("rainfall.dat");       // If the file cannot open display failed
    if(fin.fail()){
    cout << "failed" << endl;
    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have permission to read the file?

Comment: If that is the only problem (well - so far, but it is the one your question is about), then there is no need to include all the other stuff. Unless it works *without* and does not work *with*. Did you test that? See [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes I do. Both Read and Write.

Comment: Yes sorry it does everything works on Windows. I included it because I honestly have no idea what is making this not work.

Comment: Make a really stupid simple program: `int main(){ifstream fin("rainfall.dat"); if(fin.fail()){ cout << "failed" << endl; return 1; } }` and see what happens.

Comment: It still fails. It acts just like my other program

Comment: Good to know. You aren't doing anything goofy in the software then. @pm100 beat me to my next suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
#include <errno.h>

    if(fin.fail())
        perror("open failed ");
```

this will give you a human readable message for the last error

Comment: Ok so it says there is no such file or directory (which I figured is what it would say) but why? The name is right rainfall.dat is in the correct directory and if I try to put the whole file path I get the same problem.

Comment: I don't know what changed but after deleting the file and re-downloading it the program works.

Comment: Revert to Idiot Mode, just to make sure your computer is working. 1. Create a file called `a`. 2. Try this program (naturally with the correct filename!). 3a. If it works, there may be some strange character in the original name. 3b. If it doesn't, your system broke. (While I was typing). ...It seems this was 3a!